# How to automatically dump memory when old-gen of jvm exceeds some ratio?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, dump

I found my busy java web app full-gc quite often.
And I monitored the process with jstat and got the following result:

```
Timestamp         S0     S1     E      O      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT    LGCC                 GCC                 
  2265116.2   0.00  58.20  79.23  62.57  62.29 273122 5729.765   727  281.867 6011.632 unknown GCCause      No GC               
  2265117.3   0.00  58.20  86.92  62.57  62.29 273122 5729.765   727  281.867 6011.632 unknown GCCause      No GC               
  2265118.3   0.00  58.20  97.72  62.57  62.29 273122 5729.765   727  281.867 6011.632 unknown GCCause      No GC               
  2265119.3  48.51   0.00  13.06  62.84  62.29 273123 5729.791   727  281.867 6011.658 unknown GCCause      No GC               
  2265120.2  48.51   0.00  51.12  62.84  62.29 273123 5729.791   727  281.867 6011.658 unknown GCCause      No GC               
  2265121.3   0.00  42.79  35.43  65.35  62.29 273124 5729.830   727  281.867 6011.697 unknown GCCause      No GC               
  2265122.2   0.00  39.46  50.81  80.86  62.29 273126 5729.998   728  281.883 6011.881 CMS Initial Mark     No GC               
  2265123.3   4.43   4.82  75.57  97.05  62.29 273129 5730.176   729  281.883 6012.060 unknown GCCause      Allocation Failure  
  2265124.3   4.43   4.82  75.57  97.05  62.29 273129 5730.176   729  281.883 6012.060 unknown GCCause      Allocation Failure  
  2265125.3   0.00   7.89  26.93  45.03  62.27 273130 5730.259   729  283.690 6013.949 unknown GCCause      No GC               
  2265126.3   0.00   7.89  35.96  45.03  62.27 273130 5730.259   729  283.690 6013.949 unknown GCCause      No GC               
  2265127.3   0.00   7.89  44.85  45.03  62.27 273130 5730.259   729  283.690 6013.949 unknown GCCause      No GC               
  2265128.3   0.00   7.89  52.71  45.03  62.27 273130 5730.259   729  283.690 6013.949 unknown GCCause      No GC               
  2265129.3   0.00   7.89  61.61  45.03  62.27 273130 5730.259   729  283.690 6013.949 unknown GCCause      No GC
```

I could see that every 20 minutes or so, there seems to be a very huge object created in memory. It is so big that could not fit into young-gen, it is allocated in the old-gen directly.
And it often cause the whole app hit the FGC retio(which is 70%) and a FGC triggered, the big object is GC-ed immediately. So I could not determine what it is by heap dump.
This issue makes my app 'quakes' regularly.
My max heap is 3g and young-gen is 521m. The perm-gen is always stable.
So, could somebody tell me how could I know what the huge object really is?
Can I configure the jvm to dump its memory when old-gen exceeds some specified ratio?
Or any other useful methodologies could help?
Thanks very much!

Comment: Which line are you referring to?  The only jump in old gen size follows a minor collection, this is completely normal. I suspect there is no huge object.

Comment: You are doing a minor collection every couple of seconds.  I suggest you increase the Eden size so you don't have as many young collections.

Comment: I mean the percentage of old-gen usage jumps from 65.35% to 97.05% in just 2 or 3 seconds. Since my old-gen is 2.5GB large, it usually means that there's a very huge object appeared by sudden. I want to find out what it is.

Comment: Have you tried using a memory profiler?  This will show you large objects but also tell you where most of your garbage is coming from.  250 MB/second is a fairly high rate (but not unreasonable)

Comment: In the time of that jump there is two minor collections so it could be that objects have been promoted. In any case a memory profiler is your best option.

Comment: OK, maybe I would have jconsole or jvisualvm a try, thanks.

Comment: jvisualvm has a memory profiler, jconsole doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

If the big object is GC-ed by the FullGC, you could **use the class histogram to inspect the heap**.

Use  `-XX:+PrintClassHistogramBeforeFullGC` and `-XX:+PrintClassHistogramAfterFullGC.` 
This will at least show you all the different classes of objects allocated in the heap, sorted by footprint and number of instances.

This is a lightweight approach but you can at least check your hypothesis of a "one large object". After that, you can dig in with profilers, e.g. Mission Control for JDK7u40 and higher or jProfiler, both work great.

Answer (score 1):

There is a JVM flag you might find helpful: `-XX:+HeapDumpBeforeFullGC`. It will cause JVM to dump the whole heap to a file before major stop-the-world GC. The flag is *manageable*. This means you can turn it on/off in run-time via JMX with JConsole, Misson Control or even programmatically using `javax.management` API:

```
MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean bean = ManagementFactory.newPlatformMXBeanProxy(
        server,
        "com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic",
        HotSpotDiagnosticMXBean.class);
bean.setVMOption("HeapDumpBeforeFullGC", "true");
```